# Send a document to print from website on a form submit

Tags: javascript, c#, php, forms, printing

I am trying to make a simple application. Probably in C#, would be great if only is Javascript.  I am wondering, is there a way, that when a form is submitted from my website hosted on a different server not on my network, it sends a print command to my printer to print the form when submitted.  Can anyone help to explain the process that would need to take place for this to happen and even if it is even possible?  Any resources or code examples?

Comment: Think about world where an arbitrary server could send commands to your printer ...

Answer (score 1):

It's not impossible, yet more or less difficult. There are a few steps to take:

1. Create the form (OK, use HTML and perhaps JavaScript, shouldn't be that hard ;))
2. Process the form after submission by the user
3. Get the result to your network - that's the tricky part
4. Print the result

For steps 2 to 4, there are a couple of possibilities how to achieve them. Here are some simple *examples*:

- Step 2: Use PHP on the server (outside your network) for form validation and perhaps also getting it in a format useful for printing
- Step 3: Mail the processed data to an email address you created only for this process
- Step 4: (In your network) check that address regularly and if new mails are present, print them out (might also be tricky, depending on your mail client, network configuration, ...)

Please note:

- As I said, these are only examples for the possibilities. You could also have kind of a service listening in your network, which is invoked when a form is submitted, use an FTP server, ...
- Keep in mind that you give the "outside world" access to your network! Secure all the communication mechanisms thoroughly! Don't get your network details (or the email address in the example above) to show on the client but insted use the server (outside of your network) as a relay station.
- Do you really need to print out all the stuff? Besides the environmental aspect, it could get really, really much, especially if someone abuses your form!
- Treat every piece of data submitted by a client as potentially malicious and therefore inspect and validate it rigorously!

Comment: thanks for the input.  This is the thought process I was thinking about too.  The 'tricky' part is the issue I need to dig more into.

Comment: thanks for the input.  This is the thought process I was thinking about too.  The 'tricky' part is the issue I need to dig more into.  I guess I would need a small application on the server to talk and process the submission, and probably a small application on the computer, or printer server that would receive communications from the main processing server.  Now I can see why people just use email.  This would be used for orders of products, it is just nice to have the orders print out immediately on a successful payment.